# Hiding Email Address With jQuery

Tags: jquery, email

I know there are plugins that do this, but I need something pretty specific and I can't find anything.

I need a jQuery script that only change the `mailto` link, and not the text of the link. For example:

`<a href="person(at)exammple.com">Person's Email</a>`

I need to display something else inside the link besides the actual e-mail address. The script I was trying to use is from [this site](http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-mailto-links-plugin-version-11/?doing_wp_cron).

Here's the script:

```
jQuery.fn.mailto = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
        var email = $(this).html().replace(/\s*\(.+\)\s*/, "@");
        $(this).before('<a href="mailto:' + email + '" rel="nofollow" title="Email ' + email + '">' + email + '</a>').remove();
    });
};
```

I think I need to replace the "email" variable with something else in between the `<a>` tags, but I'm not sure with what. I'm still pretty new to jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.mailto = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var email_add = $(this).attr("href").replace(/\s*\(.+\)\s*/, "@");
            var email_text = $(this).html();
            $(this).before('<a href="mailto:' + email_add + '" rel="nofollow" title="Email ' + email_add + '">' + email_text + '</a>').remove();
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('.email').mailto();
    });
});
```

You can try it @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8EAg/)

Answer (score 1):

var email = $(this).html().replace('@', '(at)');

Comment: I need to do it with jQuery, unfortunately. I could probably do it with PHP, but I have specific instructions that it needs to be jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I have a jq-plug-in i made that might help.
See the [fiddle(working demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/9YHzB/)

Keep in mind the plugin ends at /* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

To use is ez:

```
$("#domElementID").jqMailTo({   //  Not all of these options are a must except for the address
    address:    ["Saab@test.net","Volvo@test.net","BMW@test.net"],  // can also be as simple as 1 string, exp -> address:'BMW@test.net',
    label:      'testLabel',
    subject:    'This is a subject',
    body:       'This is a Body section',
    cc:         'aCC@test.net',
    bcc:        'theBCC@test.com'
});
```